# Linux, openSuse on virtualBox not showing usb

Tags: linux, virtualbox, opensuse

My virtual box is installed on the host(Win 8.1).
In the virtual box, I have installed OpenSuse as the virtual machine, but I am having trouble accessing the usb in OpenSuse(vm).
I can't see any option to access the usb.
My usb is in FAT32 format,as I am trying to get some files from other win machine to openSuse.
The following are the screen shots, please let me know what all I need to do to access the USB in openSuse(vm).

[image: VirtualBox Settings on Win8 host]

[image: Cannot see any usb option in openSuse]

when I do lsusb, following is the output.

```
linux-gn77:~ # lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 80ee:0021 VirtualBox USB Tablet
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Does `lsusb` show the devices?

Comment: I have edited the question with the results that I have got from lsusb.

Comment: I am not familiar enough with VirtualBox. Maybe the filter means that these devices are filtered out? Uncheck those entries and try again.

Comment: Did you install VirtualBox guest additions?

Comment: @Questionmark I have installed the virtualBox extension pack.I think that what you mean by guest additions.

Comment: I just came across this as well with an Ubuntu host and OpenSUSE guest. I couldn't get USB to work until I disabled the USB 2.0 option in the settings. Once I did that the USB drive popped right up when selected. Trying to find if there's an existing bug for this.